# Ask Ubuntu, Community Building, and Mechanics not showing up on the network-wide mod list

Tags: bug, status-norepro, moderators, stackexchange.com

**Edit:** I've pinpointed where the problem seems to be: a few sites, such as [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Community Building](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com), and [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com), have disappeared (along with all their mods) from the network-wide moderator list. When the list is [sorted by site instead of by username](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=sites), these sites don't show up.

---

When I look at the [network-wide list of moderators, sorted by username](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=users), eighteen users appear at the very top of the list (before the alphabetically ordered list from 200_success and 2quick 4u all the way down to Zizouz12 and кяαzєя) with **no usernames at all, only avatars**:

[image]

Clicking on "show details" doesn't make anything appear there either:

[image]

<strike>I can't tell what those eighteen mods have in common - their usernames don't all contain unusual characters; they're mods on a variety of different sites (although I do spot a fair few Ask Ubuntu moderators in there); their names are spread well out through the alphabet; ...</strike> These eighteen mods are all mods on those few sites and no others (terdon, who is a mod on both Ask Ubuntu and Unix & Linux, shows up as a mod on only the latter site).

Comment: @HDE226868 *three of the last four (not Andy). But yes, you're right: it's just a small subset of sites which are being affected.

Comment: This is the next phase in modship...invisibility.

Comment: @Andy BURN THE WITCH! BURN HIM!

Comment: Mods from all three sites seem to be showing up in the list, names, site and all, so I can't repro this.

Comment: No repro, but someone did move the cheese: the sites now have Stack Exchange appended to the name, which [wasn't the case before](https://web.archive.org/web/20140117154143/http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=sites). Except those with a fancy name (and it seems "Drupal Answers" counts as a fancy name).

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yeah, I'm not seeing it any more either. Seems it was only a temporary glitch.